How should I resolve the propType required error in functional component when defaultProps is deprecated?
As per React 18.3 'defaultProps' is deprecated. So I have removed it from my functional component and used default parameter. But in my propTypes object I have made a property as required. Now since I have removed defaultProps, I am getting below warning in console.
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `loadChart` is marked as required in `HistogramChart`, but its value is `undefined`.

How should I remove this warning?

Make sure that the component using  has this "required" prop loadChart :)

npm install prop-types
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
function Football({ loadChart }) {
  
  return <div>{loadChart}</div>;
}
Football.propTypes = {
  loadChart: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
export default Football;

make sure you pass function value in parent component to remove this warning as you set prop require
